# ServiceStack OrmLite Is it a error to use UserAuthRepository.CreateUserAuth inside a transaction

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a complex workflow where I want to create rows in several tables in one transaction.
One of the operations is to create a new UserAuth (from ServiceStack Authentication feature).

I assume that all the database operations in a transaction should operate on the same connection, and if that is true, then I think it may be a problem to call UserAuthRepository.CreateUserAuth inside a transaction because it looks as if it uses its own connection.

So my question is whether if the creation of a UserAuth will be part of the transaction or not when I have code like shown below. And if not, then how to go about creating new users as part of an transaction?

```
  using (var db = Db.OpenDbConnection()) {
    using (var trans = db.OpenTransaction()) {

      ... do some databae operations via. db ...

      var userAuth = UserAuthRepository.CreateUserAuth(
        new UserAuth{UserName = "blabla"}, 
        "password"
      );

      ... do some more databae operations via. db ...

      trans.Commit(); 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally whenever ServiceStack requires accessing a database, e.g in the [OrmLiteUserAuthRepository.CreateUserAuth](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs#L60) it asks for and uses a new connection and immediately disposes of it once it's done.

There is currently no way to make it apart of a custom transaction.